# iOS Localization Best Practice for UILabel + UIButton

Tags: ios, localization, nsstring

I think most developers have encountered this problem when trying to do localization of an app for multiple languages.

For example, I need to localize the below sentence into different languages, however there are some **words that users can click to go to another page**. Now, it is very hard to make them still alligned properly as a whole sentence if words in other languages are longer or shorter than English, **especially when there are two clickable parts**. For the clicking part, I think we can only use **UIButton**, or are there any other good suggestions? I believe there must be some industrialized way to do this.

"Terms" and "Privacy Policy" are clickable:

[image]

Comment: Here, you are supposed to use an NSMutableAttributedString and present it in UITextView for this to happen.

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanyaAmjuri I just realized that I could open an url with UITextView. However, I still didn't figure out if it is possible to make a segue with NSMutableAttributedString. Any suggestions? Thanks!!

Comment: I believe we can by using UITextViewDelegate. I'm just checking for that

Comment: Yes, finally wrote the answer. It's working. Please check it and feel free to suggest edits to make it better :)

Comment: check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010153/make-clickable-uilabel-using-swift/47004773#47004773

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you can follow the following steps to get your job done.

1. Create an NSMutableString

   ```
   NSString *initString = @"You agree to our terms and policy";
   NSMutableAttributedString *nsms = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:initString];
   [nsms addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor greenColor] range:[initString rangeOfString:@"terms"]];
   [nsms addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor greenColor] range:[initString rangeOfString:@"policy"]];
   [nsms addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15] range:NSMakeRange(0, initString.length)];
   [nsms addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40311151/ios-localization-best-practice-for-uilabel-uibutton"] range:[initString rangeOfString:@"policy"]];`
   ```
2. Set the attributed string to the UITextView

   ```
   UITextView *TextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - 40, 100)];
   TextView.delegate = self;
   TextView.attributedText = nsms;
   TextView.editable = NO;
   [self.view addSubview:TextView];
   ```
3. Inside the delegate function for UITextView

   ```
   - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange interaction:(UITextItemInteraction)interaction {

          // According to range condition/url condition
         [self goToOtherPage];
         return NO;
   }
   ```

Here, `goToOtherPage` is just a custom function in which you can write code for your segue

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "You agree to our ")

let string2 = NSAttributedString(string: "Terms", attributes: [NSLinkAttributeName:"http://www.google.com"])

let string3 = NSAttributedString(string: " and ")

let string4 = NSAttributedString(string: "Conditions", attributes: [NSLinkAttributeName:"http://www.google.com"])

attrString.append(string2)
attrString.append(string3)
attrString.append(string4)

label.attributedText = attrString
```

**EDIT:**

You can better use TTTAttributedLabel. It's a subclass of UILabel. https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel

More info here: [Make Clickable UILabel Using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010153/make-clickable-uilabel-using-swift)

Comment: Is it possible to make a segue with NSMutableAttributedString? I haven't found anything yet for that.

Comment: @Chenya Zhang Simply clicking on link in NSMutableAttributedString contained in UITextView will normally redirect you to the web page. If we use delegate function for url interaction in UITextView. We can achieve your task by calling segue function inside that UITextView delegate function