# Swift - Present UIAlertController in extension function

Tags: swift, function, label, uialertcontroller

I've wrote a label extension which detect links in the label.
It's attributed text with NSLinkAttributeName for links and I'm using 
`func handleTapOnLabel(_ tapGesture:UITapGestureRecognizer){}` to detect where is the tap and which link to choose to open. The problem is that I use the function in extension for UILabel and I want to present an UIAlertController to ask the person - "You are about to open this link in Safari. Would you like to proceed?"... So I can't access viewcontroller to use the function `present(UIAlertController...` to display the alert. Any suggestions how this can be happened in extension? How to access label's viewcontroller directly from extension ?

Comment: 1) You can pass ViewController object(vcObj) in extension's method.
2) You can present UIAlertController on top most ViewController in ViewController's hierarchy.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010153/make-clickable-uilabel-using-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1) Present UIAlertController on top most ViewController in ViewController's hierarchy

```
extension UILabel { //your extension
   func openLinkAction() {  //your extension custom method
     //code 
      if var topController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController {
        while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
            topController = presentedViewController
        }
      }

    // topController should now be your topmost view controller
    // present alert on this controller 
}
       //and present here with vcInstance
   }
}
```

Method 2) Pass ViewController's object as parameter

```
extension UILabel { //your extension
   func openLink(vc: UIViewController) { //your extension custom method function
       // code
       // present alert on this vc 
   }
}
```

// For getting top most controller you ca use..

```
extension UIApplication {
    class func topViewController(controller: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let navigationController = controller as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(controller: navigationController.visibleViewController)
        }
        if let tabController = controller as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tabController.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(controller: selected)
            }
        }
        if let presented = controller?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(controller: presented)
        }
        return controller
    }
}

//  topController
if let topController = UIApplication.topViewController() {

}
```

Comment: I don't want to use method 2 because I have to implemet (vc: UIViewController) in 1000 functions... about 1st method I've tried, but topController.presentedViewController is always nil? any other methods or suggestions?